# Jersey and JSON Single Element Arrays

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have JSON structure like the below:

```
{
    Quote : {
        ItemList : {
            Items : [
                {
                },
                {
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when it returns 1 item then it becomes like the below:

```
{
    Quote : {
        ItemList : {
            Items : {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

To solve this i have written the MyJAXBContextResolver class as below

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyJAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext>{
    private JAXBContext context;

    private Class[] types = {ItemList.class,Quote.class,Items.class};

    public MyJAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("Items").build(),
        types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }     
}
```

I have the necessary configuration in `web.xml`, means package and load-on-startup value i have given. So this class loaded but call to `getContext()` is not going.

Need Help.

Comment: Am i missing some configuration?

Comment: Could you please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? At least the current example does not seem to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the following code :

JSONConfiguration config = JSONConfiguration.natural().build();
JAXBContext ctx = new JSONJAXBContext(config, object.getClass());
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Marshaller u = ctx.createMarshaller();
JSONMarshaller jsonMarshaller = JSONJAXBContext.getJSONMarshaller(u, ctx);
jsonMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING , "UTF-8");
jsonMarshaller.marshallToJSON(object, writer);
result = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Rather than just attach code solving the problem, you should really attempt to explain why you have done what you have done (possibly in comments in the code), and why it has fixed the original problem (as text in the answer)